# How to find the values only for 3 inputs of same fields

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
$price = $_POST['prices'];<br>
$city = $_POST['city'];<br>
$hotels= $_POST['hotels'];<br>
```

> ```
> SELECT post_id,meta_key,meta_value<br>
>     FROM `wp_postmeta`<br>
>     WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%$price%' <br>
>     or `meta_value` LIKE 'hotels%' <br>
>     or `meta_value` LIKE '%$city%'");
> ```

I have a column name meta_value. It contain lots of values like price,hotels,city etc of items. As mention just above They all are in same column named meta_value.
 

 I mean to say $price,$hotels and $cities should be checked against meta_value.

Now my query outputs all values from the table, bt I want to get values having price or hotels or city only

Comment: use `AND` instead of `OR`

Comment: The three values are post at same time ?

Comment: yes i have to post same time. bt there can be empty value

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AND not OR

```
SELECT post_id,meta_key,meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%$price%' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'hotels%' AND `meta_value` LIKE '%$city%'");
```

http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and_or.php

Comment: No, And didnot work for me bcoz there is one field and 3 inputs.